# what is error : incompatible type for argument of fprintf?

Tags: c, file, printf, incompatibility

So I'm trying to write a code for university students. The algorithm is that they enter their name and choose the subject they want to know the grade of. Then the program should read the file and show them the grade. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void main()
{
float math_grade, biology_grade, art_grade;
char math[5];
char Biology[10];
char name[20];
char subject[20];
FILE *info;


printf("Enter name : \n");
scanf("%s", name);
info = fopen("c:\\New folder\\info.txt", "r");
fscanf(info, "%s", name);


printf("Choose subject : \n", subject);
scanf("%s", subject);


if (subject == math)
    {
        fscanf(info, "%f", math_grade);
        fprintf("Grade = %f", math_grade);
else if (subject == Biology)
        fscanf(info, "%f", biology_grade);
        fprintf("Grade = %f", biology_grade);
    
else
        fscanf(info,"%f", art_grade);
        fprintf("Grade = %f", art_grade);
    }
```

}
'''
The problem is that i encounter the error : incompatible type for argument 2 of fprintf.
Anyone knows what am I doing wrong and how should i fix this? p.s : ignore the other bugs. I didn't debug the code yet.

Comment: `fprintf` expects a `FILE` pointer.

Comment: you need to use printf, not fprintf.  fprintf is to write to a file.  printf is to write to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

```
fprintf("Grade = %f", math_grade);
```

The `fprintf` function expects a `FILE *` as its first argument.  This is why you're getting an error.  If you want to output to the console, use `printf` instead.